# C++ Vector Declaration Syntax

Tags: c++11, vector, syntax, stl, containers

Confused why vector declaration syntax is different than any other data structure. For example an Array.

`vector<int> myvector`

Whereas an array can be declared as such

`int arr[] = {1, 2}`

Comment: `std::vector` is a [template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates).

Answer (score 0):

A vector and an array are different things. Among other things, a vector change size at runtime; an array cannot.

The 'array' is built into the language, and came along from C.

`vector` is a class in the standard library.

All the STL containers are declared like vector.

```
vector<int> v;
list<int> l;
forward_list<int> fl;
array<int, 3> a;
set<int> set;
map<int, string> m;
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks but that answer my question. I understand that an object “v” is instantiated ( class vector) but why we need  <datatype> ?

Comment: *All the STL containers are declared like vector.* Strings are also containers, can be included to the list.